# How to get text from JComboBox?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, arraylist, jcombobox

I have a problem with getting text from selected position of JComboBox. I tried to use getSelectedItem method in class which extends Kodowanie.java, but i get null value and i can't find out why. Method (getSelectedItem) works in Kodowanie class I can easily get text form JComboBox .

**Kodowanie.java**

```
   public class Kodowanie {

        //Skladowe:
        ArrayList <String> qweqwe; 
        JComboBox inputCode = new JComboBox();  //HERE IS MY INPUT COMBOBOX
        JComboBox outputCode = new JComboBox();
        JTextArea input;
        JTextArea output;

    public void createGUI(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Code");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        input  = new JTextArea(); 
        output = new JTextArea();

        qweqwe = new ArrayList<>();
        napelnijTalbiceCharsetami(qweqwe); //METHOD WHICH ADD ALL CHARSETS TO LIST

        inputCode = new JComboBox(qweqwe.toArray());
        outputCode = new JComboBox(qweqwe.toArray());

        JScrollPane scrollPaneInput = new JScrollPane(input, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JScrollPane scrollPaneOutput = new JScrollPane(output, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        scrollPaneInput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Input Path"));
        scrollPaneOutput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Output Path"));

        inputCode.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,50));
        outputCode.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,50));

        scrollPaneInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        scrollPaneOutput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

        input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
             public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){  
                    Strumieniowanie tmp;
                    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                    {
                        try {
                            tmp = new Strumieniowanie(input.getText(), output.getText());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneInput);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneOutput);
        frame.getContentPane().add(inputCode);
        frame.getContentPane().add(outputCode);

        frame.setLayout(new  FlowLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 220));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private ArrayList napelnijTalbiceCharsetami(ArrayList tmp){
        Map charSets = Charset.availableCharsets();
        Iterator iterator = charSets.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
            tmp.add(iterator.next().toString());
        }
        return tmp;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Kodowanie l = new Kodowanie();
        l.createGUI();
    }



}
```

**Strumieniowanie.java**

```
public class Strumieniowanie extends Kodowanie {

    protected boolean pathInputOk = false;
    protected boolean pathOutputOk = false;

public Strumieniowanie(String tmpInpute, String tmpOutput) throws IOException {


    File plikInput = new File(tmpInpute);
    File plikOutput = new File(tmpOutput);

    String inputText;
    inputText =  (String) inputCode.getSelectedItem(); //HERE I TRY TO GET STRING FROM JCOMBOBOX BUT IT IS ALWAYS NULL !
    System.out.println(inputText);

    pathInputOk = plikInput.isFile();
    pathOutputOk = plikOutput.isFile();

    System.out.println(pathInputOk);
    System.out.println(pathOutputOk);

    if (pathInputOk && pathOutputOk) {
        File nowyPlik = new File(tmpInpute);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(nowyPlik);

        fis.close();

    }

}

protected boolean isItaPath(File plik) {
    boolean tmp = 

false;
        tmp = plik.isFile();

        return tmp;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is your `Strumieniowanie` class in the same package as `Kodowanie` class?

Comment: Yes. I even remove any access specifiers but it doesn t change anything.

Comment: For clarity & brevity, `boolean tmp = 

false;
        tmp = plik.isFile();

        return tmp;` should be replaced with `return plik.isFile();`
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KeyListener` is not the appropriate event listener to use, it is triggered BEFORE the combobox has updated its state, better to use an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

The `actionPerformed` event will be fired AFTER the combo box has updated, which will ensure that the `getSelectedItem` method will actually return the currently selected value.

Comment: So it's mean that no field was selected and that was main source of problem.

Comment: The source of the problem as we tried to intercept the event at the wrong time.  You got in (with the key listener) before the combo box, meaning when you checked the `selectedItem` method, it was still null (or the previously selected value).  The `ActionListener` is fired by the combo box AFTER it has processed the key event

Answer (score 1):

The following method can be used to get the text from a `ComboBox`.

```
String s = (String)comboOne.getSelectedItem();
```

where `comboOne` is the variable name of `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, to answer the tittle of the page : How to get text from `JComboBox`?

```
((JTextComponent)combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText()
```

It "works" but does not return any text... crap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **KeyListener** but instead of adding it directly, insert it using

```
comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener();
```

This will make sure that listener is being added to Editor of JComboBox

To get text from it use:

```
comboBox.getEditor().getItem();
```

this will get the text directly from the editor, you can use it below keyReleased to get text from editor as you type

Answer (score 0):

`combobox.getEditor().getItem().toString` worked for me.

You can add `documentListener` to listen to the changes of input.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).